# bash finding files in directories recursively

Tags: bash, recursion

I'm studying the bash shell and lately understood i'm not getting right recursive calls involving file searching- i know find is made for this but I'm recently asked to implement a certain search this way or another.

I wrote the next script:

```
#!/bin/bash


function rec_search {
for file in `ls $1`; do
echo ${1}/${item}
if[[ -d $item ]]; then
rec ${1}/${item}
fi
done
}

rec $1
```

the script gets as argument  file and looking for it recursively.
i find it a poor solution of mine. and have a few improvement questions:

1. how to find files that contain spaces in their names
2. can i efficiently use `pwd` command for printing out absolute address (i tried so, but unsuccessfully)
3. every other reasonable improvement of the code

Comment: [Don't use `ls`!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: @Inian `find` is not a built-in command in *any* shell.

Comment: @chepner: Agreed it should have been `GNU findutils`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script currently cannot work:

- The function is defined as `rec_search`, but then it seems you mistakenly call `rec`
- You need to put a space after the "if" in `if[[`

There are some other serious issues with it too:

- `` for file in `ls $1` `` goes against the recommendation to "never parse the output of `ls`", won't work for paths with spaces or other whitespace characters
- You should indent the body of `if` and `for` to make it easier to read

The script could be fixed like this:

```
rec() {
    for path; do
        echo "$path"
        if [[ -d "$path" ]]; then
            rec "$path"/*
        fi
    done
}
```

But it's best to not reinvent the wheel and use the `find` command instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `bash` 4 or later (which is likely unless you running this under Mac OS X), you can use the `**` operator.

```
rec () {
  shopt -s globstar
  for file in "$1"/**/*; do
    echo "$file"
  done
}
```